# Apache Airflow error "Please run `airflow db init`" in Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I try to use the official Apache Airflow guide in [Docker Compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) . I want to modify the Dockerfile and add at least `VIM` (according to the guide) and install libs `requirements.txt`.

It works When I use original image

```yaml
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:latest-python3.10}
  # build: .
```

But when I change

```yaml
  # image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.1-python3.10}
  build: .
```

I got an error

```
airflow-init-1  | ERROR: You need to initialize the database. Please run `airflow db init`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.8.1.
airflow-init-1  | 2.8.1
```

Dockerfile (1-1 from guide):

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.1-python3.10

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         vim \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
```

It works if I remove this part, but I want to install libs by this way:

```
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm not sure that it's 100% solution, but I fix my error by removing all unnecessary libs from requirements.txt. I created it from prod env python, where was SQLAlchemy, alembic, e.t.c so perhaps one of them overwrote the Airflow version of the dependency